# Maximum a posteriori parameter estimation of normal inverse gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, partial-derivative, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I am trying to estimate the mean and the variance of normal distribution using Maxima a posteriori (MAP). The parameters $\theta$ are found by maximizing the a posteriori probability:
$$
\theta_* = {\rm argmax}_{\theta} p(\theta | X) = {\rm argmax}_{\theta} p(X| \theta) p(\theta)
$$
In my case. $\theta = (\mu, \sigma^2)$ and both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown. $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ is the feature space.

However the derived variance is not fitting the ground truth gaussian.

In order to obtain the expression for posterior probability I use a [Conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior). Since likelihood function has a continuous distribution, I am using the [Normal inverse gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse-gamma_distribution):
$$
p(\mu, \sigma^2) = \mbox{NIG}(\mu, \sigma^2 | \mu_0, \nu, \alpha, \beta) = \frac{\sqrt{\nu}}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{\alpha+1} \exp\left[-\frac{2\beta + \nu(\mu_0 - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right] \,\, (1)
$$

Now I am going to find the argmax of likelihood and prior probabilites.
For each measurement $x \in X$, expressing probabilities I get:
$$
p(X| \theta) p(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^N(\frac{\sqrt{\nu}}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{\alpha+1} \exp\left[-\frac{2\beta + \nu(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]) \\ \phantom{...................}
\frac{\sqrt{\nu}}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{\alpha+1} \exp\left[-\frac{2\beta + \nu(\mu_0 - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right] \,\, (2)
$$

Putting things together, (2) can be expressed as:
$$
L = \left(\frac{\sqrt{\nu}}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{\alpha+1}\right)^{n+1}
\exp\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(\frac{2\beta + \nu(x_i - \mu)^2}{-2\sigma^2}\right)+\frac{2\beta + \nu(\mu_0 - \mu)^2}{-2\sigma^2}\right] \, (3)
$$

To make future estimation easier, I will take logarithm of (3). Since logarithm is a monotonic function, it won't change the optimal result.
$$
{\rm log}(L) = l = (n+1){\rm log}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\nu}}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{\alpha+1}\right) + \frac{2N\beta}{-2\sigma^2} + \frac{\nu\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\mu)^2}{-2\sigma^2} + \frac{2\beta+\nu(\mu_0-\mu)^2}{-2\sigma^2} = \\
\frac{(n+1)}{2}{\rm log}\left(\frac{\nu}{2\pi\sigma^2}\right) + (n+1){\rm log}\left(\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\right) + 2(n+1)(\alpha + 1){\rm log}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}\right) + \frac{2N\beta}{-2\sigma^2} + \frac{\nu\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\mu)^2}{-2\sigma^2} + \frac{2\beta+\nu(\mu_0-\mu)^2}{-2\sigma^2} \,\,\, (4)
$$

To find optimal mean and variance, I will look when their partial derivatives equal zero:
$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mu} = \frac{\nu}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\mu) + \frac{\nu}{\sigma^2} \nu(\mu_0-\mu) = \frac{\nu}{\sigma^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i-N\mu+\nu\mu_0-\nu\mu\right) = 0
$$
if
$$
\nu\mu+N\mu = \sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i+\nu\mu_0
$$
thus
$$
\mu = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i+\nu\mu_0}{\nu+N}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma} = \frac{N+1}{\sigma}-(N+1)(\alpha+1)\frac{1}{\sigma}+\frac{2N\beta}{\sigma^3}+\frac{\nu\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\nu)^2}{\sigma^3}+\frac{2\beta}{\sigma^3}+\frac{\nu(\mu_0-\mu)^2}{\sigma^3} = 
\frac{1}{\sigma}\left(-2N\alpha-2\alpha-3N-3+\frac{2N\beta}{\sigma^2}+\frac{\nu\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\nu)^2}{\sigma^2}\frac{2\beta}{\sigma^2}+\frac{\nu(\mu_0-\mu)}{\sigma^2}\right) = 0
$$
if the expression in brackets is zero. Therefore
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{2N\beta+\nu\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\nu)^2+2\beta+\nu(\mu_0-\mu)}{2N\alpha+2\alpha+3N+3}
$$

On real data, the mean is ok, but the variance is not fitting the gaussian as it is supposed to fit more with more data samples. See in
[estimated parameters plot experiment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhW6G.png), where the maximum likelihood estimation (ML) fits but the MAP do not fit as it is excepted to converge to ML.

Maybe, I done something wrong in the parameter derivation. Any ideas where 
I could make mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The large bug is in which probabilities I took to express the posterior probability (posterior = likelihood * hyperprior, NOT posterior = hyperprior * hyperprior).

Then, the correct posterior is:
$$
p(X| \theta) p(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)
\frac{\sqrt{\nu}}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{\alpha+1} \exp\left[-\frac{2\beta + \nu(\mu_0 - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]
$$

After taking logarithm of posterior, parameter estimation from the derivative equal zero is for:

mean:
$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mu} = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i-N\mu+\nu\mu_0-\nu\mu\right) = 0
$$
if
$$
\mu = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i+\nu\mu_0}{\nu+N}
$$

variance:
$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma} = \frac{1}{\sigma}\left(-N-2\alpha-3+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}+\frac{2\beta}{\sigma^2}+\frac{\nu(\mu_0-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right) = 0
$$

if
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\mu)^2+2\beta+\nu(\mu_0-\mu)^2}{N+2\alpha+3}
$$

Note that for both correct an incorrect derivations, the estimated mean is the same, which should not, and that confuses me.